# Does this formula holds true for $|x|>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, chebyshev-polynomials

When the first two Chebyshev polynomials $T₀(x)$ and $T₁(x)$ are known, all other polynomials $T_{n}(x),n≥2$ can be obtained by means of the recurrence formula
$$T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_{n}(x)-T_{n-1}(x)$$

My **question** is:

Does this formula holds true for $|x|>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence generates new polynomials, and polynomials are always defined for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

So, **yes**, it also holds for $|x| > 1$.